# NavigationBar hides on the 2nd time I'm opening viewController (SWRevealViewController in)

Tags: swift, hide, navigationbar, swrevealviewcontroller

I've strange trouble with swRevealViewController.

I have 3 VC. On each of them I have navigationBar and item in it in left side which opens sideBarMenu. And trouble happens when I'm opening root view controller at second time - navigation bar hides

Project consists of main VC, navigationController, 3 VC and one tableViewController. This VC (which is problematic) is set as root VC from navigationController. Main VC (which is blank) is set as initial

I've recorded short video to show the problem

https://youtu.be/EY_IGRKN8Ro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell from the video because you didn't show the entire storyboard, but make sure that each view controller you have is embedded in a navigation controller. The slide out menu table that you use to segue to the other VC's should have a segue from that cell into the desired navigation controller. I hope this helps

Comment: I found that there is another navBar (came from nothing) which shows on the second time and its blank as it is. I deleted this VC and recreated it for many timer but this fcking bar appeared every time. How can I delete it? http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Snimokekrana2015-09-06v22.1441567191.png

Comment: I found that this shit adds when I'm doing segue from navController like "root view controller" to this problematic VC

Comment: Make sure both the slide out menu and the Reveal View Controller are both hooked up to the same navigation controller of the root VC. Since its the first view controller shown it needs to be connected to both but all the other ones only need to be connected to the slide out menu controller.